# Puxar um form C# em VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

**Puxar um form C# em VB**

Bom eu queria saber como eu poderia ta puxando um form em C#
via Visual basic 
exemplo:

[image: Imagem Demonstrativa]

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser incluir o arquivo `Loading.cs` no seu projeto Visual Basic, **isso não é possível.** Os compiladores lidam com apenas um tipo de linguagem no mesmo projeto. Você terá que reescrever o código em C# no seu projeto em VB.Net.

Alternativamente, você poderá referenciar o projeto em C# no seu VB.Net e utilizar o conteúdo do outro projeto no seu.

Para isso, referencie o projeto do C# para o projeto Visual Basic e instancie a classe do outro projeto no seu:

```vb
Imports <caminho.para.sua.form>  ' aqui é o namespace de onde sua classe Loading está
...
Dim janela As New Loading
janela.Show()
```

> Observação: a classe `Loading` deve ser pública (`public`) para o outro projeto poder acessá-la.

---

### Mas como referencio um projeto no outro?

1. Dentro do projeto em VB.NET, clique com o direito em referências:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Selecione o seu projeto em C# na aba "Projetos":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Clique em OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro https://imgur.com/43qaXUU

ja deixei a classe loading public

Comment: @C0DE substitua o `<Loading>` pelo caminho (namespace) de onde sua classe `Loading` está.

Comment: Não entendi poderia me falar um exemplo

Comment: @C0DE `Imports NomeDoProjeto.Janelas`, dentro de `Janelas` tem a classe `Loading`.

Comment: Parece que ele esta dando erro https://imgur.com/K522X1N
https://imgur.com/zm8bOUr

Comment: No `Loading.janelas` você precisa substituir com o namespace da classe `Loading`. Na sua pergunta, você não especifica o namespace. [Mas o que é um Namespace?](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces)

Comment: https://imgur.com/GwwlyJd Minha namespace e essa